# How to show $\sum x^n (1-x)$ does not converge uniformly on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

How to show $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n (1-x)$ does not converge uniformly on $[0,1]$? Can I apply Weierstrass M test here? Hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Weierstrass $M$-test can only be used to show uniform convergence (its converse is not true). Compute the pointwise limit and show that it is discontinuous. The uniform limit of continuous functions must be continuous, so you then see that the convergence here cannot be uniform.

Comment: Isn't $\lim_{n \to \infty } f_n(x) = 0 $ since $x \in [0, 1]$ is continuous?

Comment: Towards that end, think of Geometric series when finding the pointwise limit for $x\in(0,1)$ and note the sum has value $0$ when  $x=1$...

Comment: wasn't it telescoping .. that produced $x^n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum does not converge uniformly on $[0,1)$.

To wit, the $n$th rest is $R_n(x)=\sum\limits_{k=n}^{+\infty}x^k(1-x)=x^n$ hence $\sup\limits_{0\leqslant x\lt1}R_n(x)=1$, which does not converge to $0$ when $n\to\infty$.